# Replace a unix timestamp in csv file. Newline issue

Tags: awk

I have a command that outputs to stdout lines like:

```
1508425884.382198,30
1508425885.383406,30
```

I want to replace a unixtimestamp `1508485425.712408` with another date format in place.

I tried following cases:

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '$1 { system( "date -d @" $1 ); print $2}'
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '$1 { print strftime("%F %H:%M", $1); print $2}'
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '$1 { print strftime("%c", $1); print $2}'
```

But unfortunately everyone outputs after the date the character of the end of the line. With first case I also tried to add `tr -d '\n'` with pipe like following:

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '$1 { system( "date -d @" $1 "| tr -d '\n'" $1 ); print $2}'
```

But it seems non-working solution.

That's was I getting:

```
Thu Oct 19 18:11:24 +03 2017
30
Thu Oct 19 18:11:25 +03 2017
30
```

That's what I'am looking for:

```
Thu Oct 19 18:11:24 +03 2017, 30
Thu Oct 19 18:11:25 +03 2017, 30
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` statement outputs all its arguments on a separate line.
Just use a singe `print` statement:

```
awk -F',' '{ print strftime("%c", $1),$2 }' OFS=','
```